# IntelliJ Javadoc adding an additional asterisk every line

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

I'm having an obscure bug with IntelliJ javadoc formatting. Whenever I create a javadocor add a new line, it is adding a second asterisk after my cursor which is very annoying to deal with.

Here's a gif of what happens when I try to write javadocs: http://gyazo.com/4f8cf0727e545715afe02658a08edbe1

Comment: Do you have any non-bundled plugins installed?

Comment: Yes, the issue was probably with the markdown plugin since * is uses as an opening and closing tag. Completely forgot about plugins since I had so few.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did removing the markdown plugin work?
Because I had the same problem and I can reliable cause it by activating the plugin for [gauge version 0.0.3](https://github.com/getgauge/Intellij-Plugin).

Any other plugin doesn't make a jot of difference.

Comment: Yes it was actually the gauge plugin, not markdown.